# Calculate Date/Time Difference between two dates("yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") in WSO2 EI 6.5.0 using script mediator

Tags: javascript, datetime-format, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to get Date Time difference between two dates by using JavaScript functionalities in WSO2 EI Script Mediator.

Code:

```
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[var log = mc.getServiceLog(); 
  log.info("Logging inside Script Mediator");  
var resolved_date= new Date("2021-07-13 10:23:04");
var current_date = new Date("2021-07-13 11:23:04");

var diff = current_date .getTime() - resolved_date.getTime();

var Hrs = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60);
log.info("Time difference::" + Hrs); 
]]></script>
```

But it gives output like below

```
Time difference::NaN
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: What's the value of `diff`?

Comment: Hi @ThomasSablik

For diff also got value as "NaN". is there any other simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some solution. Please add any other better solution for the same.

```
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[var log = mc.getServiceLog(); 
  log.info("Logging inside Script Mediator"); 
  var  simpleDateFormat = Packages.java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
var resolved_date="2021-07-13 09:23:04";
var current_date = "2021-07-13 11:23:04";
var fomatter = new simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
var d1 = fomatter.parse(resolved_date);
var d2 = fomatter.parse(current_date);
var difference_In_Time= d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
log.info("difference_In_Time::" +difference_In_Time); 
var  difference_In_Minutes= (difference_In_Time/ (1000 * 60))% 60;
log.info("difference_In_Minutes ::" +difference_In_Time); 
var difference_In_Hours= (difference_In_Time/ (1000 * 60 * 60))% 24;
log.info("difference_In_Hours   ::" +difference_In_Time); 
]]></script>
```

Output:

```
difference_In_Time::7200000
difference_In_Minutes   ::7200000
difference_In_Hours     ::7200000
```